# Angular 6 variable not resolved in Google Chrome (web component)

Tags: angular, observable, angular-elements

Using Angular 6 I created a web component that is integrated from another application. Everything works on all browsers when running without an integration. When the web component is integrated in an other application it works on IE, Safari, FF but not on Chrome.

I managed to identify the problem. The first call gets some configuration data from my backend. It's supposed to be written into the var `this.conf`, but that does not happen in Chrome when being integrated.

My component:

```
public conf: any;

ngOnInit() {
  this.getData();
  console.log('Conf ngOnInit:', this.conf);
}

getData() {
  return this.partnerService.getData(this.name)
    .subscribe(
      (partner: any) => {
        console.log('partner: ', partner);
        this.conf = {
          id: partner['id'],
          name: partner['name']
        }
        console.log('conf:', this.conf);
     )
}
```

Partner Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class PartnerService {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getData(name: string) {
    return this.http.get(environment.apiUrl + 'partners/conf/' + name)
      .map(resp => resp['partner']);
  }
}
```

My view:

```
<pre>Conf: {{ conf | json }}</pre>
```

Console output:

```
Conf ngOnInit: undefined
partner: {id: 1, name: "xxx", booking_name: "xxx", …}
conf: {id: 1, name: "xxx"}
```

The var did not get resolved in the view. What could this be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inject the `ChangeDetectorRef` in the constructor of the view component:

```
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
}
```

In the subscribe function try:

```
this.conf = {};
this.conf.id = partner['id'];
this.conf.name = partner['name'];
this.cd.detectChanges();
```

It could be an issue with the timing/change detection tick, that's only showing in Chrome. At the very least it will rule that out of the equation

Comment: Thank you very much Dave, I didn't know about this ChangeDetectorRef :)

Comment: This was the ultimate fix for me: https://www.npmjs.com/package/elements-zone-strategy

Answer (score 0):

Edit: New Solution. try:

```
<pre *ngIf="conf && conf.id && conf.name">Conf: {{ conf | json }}</pre>
```

Comment: if you put <pre>Conf: {{ conf.id }}</pre> is data rendered?

Comment: No unfortunately not.

Comment: you should do a runneable piece of your code on some website like stackblizt. then we can help you, without more code, i cant do more :S

Comment: A runnable piece of code is almost impossible in this case. There would have to be one that creates the webcomponent (and releases it) and one that uses this released web component. How should this be done?

Comment: i dont know if you are getting problems with render of html, can you try the new solution and let me know if works for you?

Comment: It's still not shown in Google Chrome, same as before. I don't think its a render problem, it must be a watch problem or a Google bug :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you-re problem is for the async flow ... when you consol.log your `console.log('Conf ngOnInit:', this.conf);` in nginit ..it is not yet filled with result of the `this.partnerService.getData(this.name)`

try this>

```
public conf: any;

ngOnInit() {
      this.getData().subscribe(()=>{
     console.log('Conf ngOnInit:', this.conf);
});


}

getData() {
  return Observable.From(this.partnerService.getData(this.name)
    .subscribe(
      (partner: any) => {
        console.log('partner: ', partner);

        this.conf = {};
         this.conf.id = partner['id'];
          this.conf.name: partner['name'];
        console.log('conf:', this.conf);
     ))
}
```

Comment: I know that the console.log is not filled due to async, however, due to data-binding I would expect the view to be notified when the this.conf var is set. Correct?

Comment: What do you mean with webcomponent? It is not visible from your example that a webcomponent is involved. Do you use OnPush change detection strategy? that would explain the problem.

Comment: No the 2 way binding wil not update the value .. maybe if yu use | $async it could be .. or use the subscribe like  my example.. give a try!!